# Neovim steals line of screen

Tags: neovim

I try to switch to neovim because vim had turned slow.
But neovim has the irritating habit of showing two status lines at the bottom of the screen. Is it possible to merge them into one?

neovim:

```
algobase.h [RO]                                          376,7          81%
"algobase.h" [readonly] 472 lines --79%--
```

vim:

```
"algobase.h" [readonly] 472 lines --15%--                72,0-1        16%
```

Comment: This could be the cmdheight option, or statusline option, or laststatus option. Neovim has different defaults

Comment: Does this happen with `vim --clean` and `nvim --clean`? I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: If vim "turned slow," I'm guessing you're running a lot of plugins, and trying to use the same plugins with neovim. One or more of them is causing this, and probably any other problems you're having.